# Rails 310 Redirect Loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, redirect, controller

I'm going back to write a basic app with projects that have tasks.  In my show view of a project I want to list the tasks and also include a form.  When I wire this all up I get 310 Redirect loop.  It's been a while since I've written anything from scratch so would appreciate some help looking at my code.

controller code:

```
def show
     @project = Project.find(params[:id])
     @task = @project.tasks.new(params[:task])

     if @task.save
         redirect_to @project, :notice => "Task added"
       else
         render action: :show
       end
   end
```

view code:

```
<%= @project.project_name %>
<%= form_for(@task) do |m| %>
<%= m.label :Task %>
<%= m.text_field :task_name %>
<%= m.button :submit %>
<% end %>
<% @project.tasks.each do |t| %>
  <%= t.task_name %>
<% end %>
```

project.rb

```
has_many :tasks
```

task.rb

```
belongs_to :project
```

Answer (score 0):

You are redirecting to `@project`, which is interpreted as meaning, redirect to the show page for `@product`. But you are calling redirect *from* the show page, hence the redirect loop:

1. request routed to show page
2. find project
3. task instantiated
4. task saved
5. redirect to show (loop back to 2)

Normally you don't create records in `show`, you do it in `create`. Any reason you're doing it this way?